# How can I tell if I have a bug with my kernel or with my UEFI firmware?

Tags: kernel, bios, uefi

I have a dz77ga-70k motherboard with version 0049 of the Intel firmware on it. Linux and elilo will not boot in uefi mode. The symptoms are that when I run `bzImage.efi initrd=initrd.img ro debug loglevel=8 earlyprinkt=vga root=/dev/sda2` from the uefi shell, it hangs. And elilo will reboot after selecting the kernel.

Then I compiled the latest kernel source and that failed too. I have added some debugging output to the source, specifically `arch/x86/boot/compressed/eboot.c` and what *seems* to be happening is that the call to `exit_boot_services` is failing all the time. This also happens with elilo.

From the [uefi spec](http://www.uefi.org/specs/download/2_3_1_ErrataC.pdf), the only reason that `exit_boot_services` should fail is because the memory map has "changed" between `get_memory_map` and exit_boot_services.

I'm usually a graphics programmer and don't know much about the kernel/bios stuff, so how can I tell if this is a bug with the firmware or the kernel? I don't mind doing some testing.

It seems that other people are having a similar problem with a similar motherboard: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.redhat.fedora.devel/167170

Looking at the 8 segment led status codes on the mb, it goes C6 -> start kernel -> F8 -> B1  then hangs. F8 is ExitBootServices and B0 to BF is "detecting and initing fixed media" so maybe it is getting past ExitBootServices?

Any clues?

Comment: Try another bootloader, I had some issue a few months ago (using grub legacy) - as soon as I used syslinux it worked fine, though I must admit I have no clue why (GA-Z77X-D3H in my case in EFI mode).

Comment: According to [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Syslinux) syslinux does not support uefi booting at the moment, only bios. I think my title may have been misleading, I am trying to boot in uefi mode, bios mode works.

Comment: The BIOS/EFI "thing" said it would boot in efi mode, though I can not say if it had an autofallback to BIOS in case efi failed. Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it was a bug with the UEFI firmware, as described in the release notes for [intels 0053](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=21844&ProdId=3442&lang=eng&OSVersion=%0A&DownloadType=BIOS) firmware update. However DO NOT install it. It will brick your motherboard! Well done intel. Yet another reason not to have UEFI.